# Numpy multiplication of matrix and 3 dimensional array

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to multiply a k by k matrix, let's say,

```
W=np.array([[W_11,...,W_1k],...,[W_k1,...W_kk]])
```

(where the W_ij are numbers)
and a (k,m,m) multidimensional array, let's say,

```
A=np.array([A_1,...,A_k])
```

where A_i are m by m matrices.

If

```
A_i=[a_i]
```

where the a_i are numbers then the numpy.dot

C=np.dot(W,A) just yields the normal matrix vector product, i.e C has shape (k,1) and one has that

C[i]=np.array([W_i1*a_1+W_i2*a_2+...W_ik*a_k])

What I would like to know is what is the best way to multiply W and A where now A is not necessarily a vector, i.e A_i are m by m matrices in such a way that it mimics the product as if A_i=[a_i], i.e I would like C=np.dot(W,A) to have shape (k,m,m) and C[i] should be the m by m matrix

W_i1*A_1+...W_ik*A_k

Of course I can do this with a loop but I'm looking for an efficient solution.

Comment: Look into np.einsum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand from your question, you can use `numpy.einsum`:

```
C = np.einsum('ij,jkl->ikl', W, A)
```

Should do the job.